# BIC and RMSE are Contradict each other for ARIMA Model Selection using R: Do I Err in Theory or in Practice?

Tags: r, arima, model-selection, bic, rms

I was surprised to see that **RMSE** and **BIC** have contradictory trends for the same time-series data.

**EDITED**

The procedures in my code are:

1. simulate a 15 `AR` series of other `1, 0, 0` with `phi = 0.9`
2. chunk the series to `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14` sizes.
3. For each size, resample `1000` times with replacement for each size to form a series.
4. Obtain the `RMSE` for the newly form series along with there chunk sizes

My objective is to check which newly formed series that best perform by choosing the leat `RMSE`.

**Here is my R code for RMSE**

```
## Load packages and prepare multicore process
library(forecast)
library(future.apply)
plan(multisession)
library(parallel)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
n_cores <- detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(n_cores)
registerDoParallel(cores = detectCores())


library("ggplot2")
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

## simulate ARIMA(1,0, 0)
set.seed(927820)
seed927820 <- arima.sim(n=15, model=list(ar=0.9, order=c(1, 0, 0)), sd=1)
auto.arima(N15_ar0.9_seed927820, ic="aicc")
########################################################
## create a vector of block sizes
t <- length(seed927820)    # the length of the time series
lb <- seq(t-1) #seq(t-2)+1   # vector of block sizes to be 1 < l < n (i.e to be between 1 and n exclusively)
########################################################
## This section create matrix to store block means
BOOTSTRAP <- matrix(nrow = 1, ncol = length(lb))
colnames(BOOTSTRAP) <- lb
########################################################
## This section use foreach function to do detail in the brace
#set.seed(123, kind = "L'Ecuyer-CMRG")
BOOTSTRAP <- foreach(b = 1:length(lb), .combine = 'cbind') %dopar%{
  l <- lb[b]# block size at each instance 
  m <- ceiling(t / l)                                 # number of blocks
  blk <- split(N15_ar0.9_seed927820, rep(1:m, each=l, length.out = t))  # divides the series into blocks
  ######################################################
  set.seed(5)
  res<-sample(blk, replace=T, 1000)        # resamples the blocks
  res.unlist <- unlist(res, use.names = FALSE)   # unlist the bootstrap series
  train <- head(res.unlist, round(length(res.unlist) - 10)) # Train set
  test <- tail(res.unlist, length(res.unlist) - length(train)) # Test set
  nfuture <- forecast::forecast(train, model = forecast::auto.arima(train), lambda=0, biasadj=TRUE, h = length(test))$mean        # makes the `forecast of test set
  RMSE <- Metrics::rmse(test, nfuture)      # RETURN RMSE
  BOOTSTRAP[b] <- RMSE
}
BOOTSTRAPS <- matrix(BOOTSTRAP, nrow = 1, ncol = length(lb))
colnames(BOOTSTRAPS) <- lb
BOOTSTRAPS
df <- t(BOOTSTRAPS)
df <- data.frame(lb, df)
colnames(df) <- c("lb","RMSE")
write.csv(df, "lb_NBB_RMSE_N15_ar0.9_seed927820.csv", row.names = FALSE)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -lb) %>%
  mutate(lb = factor(lb)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = lb, y = value, color = name, group = name)) +
  geom_line() +
  xlab('lb')
```

[image: RMSE line chart]

**Here is my code for BIC**

**EDITED**

**The procedures in my R code are:**

1. simulate a 15 `AR` series of other `1, 0, 0` with `phi = 0.9`
2. chunk the series to `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14` sizes.
3. For each size, resample `1000` times with replacement for each size to form a series.
4. Obtain the `BIC` for the newly form series along with there chunk sizes

My objective is to check which newly formed series that best perform by choosing the leat `BIC`.

**Here is the outcome for RMSE**

```
## Load packages and prepare multicore process
library(forecast)
library(future.apply)
plan(multisession)
library(parallel)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
n_cores <- detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(n_cores)
registerDoParallel(cores = detectCores())


library("ggplot2")
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

## simulate ARIMA(1,0, 0)
set.seed(927820)
seed927820 <- arima.sim(n=15, model=list(ar=0.9, order=c(1, 0, 0)), sd=1)
auto.arima(N15_ar0.9_seed927820, ic="aicc")
########################################################
## create a vector of block sizes
t <- length(seed927820)    # the length of the time series
lb <- seq(t-1) #seq(t-2)+1   # vector of block sizes to be 1 < l < n (i.e to be between 1 and n exclusively)
########################################################
## This section create matrix to store block means
BOOTSTRAP <- matrix(nrow = 1, ncol = length(lb))
colnames(BOOTSTRAP) <- lb
########################################################
## This section use foreach function to do detail in the brace
#set.seed(123, kind = "L'Ecuyer-CMRG")
BOOTSTRAP <- foreach(b = 1:length(lb), .combine = 'cbind') %dopar%{
  l <- lb[b]# block size at each instance 
  m <- ceiling(t / l)                                 # number of blocks
  blk <- split(N15_ar0.9_seed927820, rep(1:m, each=l, length.out = t))  # divides the series into blocks
  ######################################################
  set.seed(5)
  res<-sample(blk, replace=T, 1000)        # resamples the blocks
  res.unlist <- unlist(res, use.names = FALSE)   # unlist the bootstrap series
  mod <- forecast::auto.arima(res.unlist)
  BICc <- BIC(mod)      # RETURN AIC
  BOOTSTRAP[b] <- BICc
}
BOOTSTRAPS <- matrix(BOOTSTRAP, nrow = 1, ncol = length(lb))
colnames(BOOTSTRAPS) <- lb
BOOTSTRAPS
df <- t(BOOTSTRAPS)
df <- data.frame(lb, df)
colnames(df) <- c("lb","RMSE")
write.csv(df, "lb_NBB_RMSE_N15_ar0.9_seed927820.csv", row.names = FALSE)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -lb) %>%
  mutate(lb = factor(lb)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = lb, y = value, color = name, group = name)) +
  geom_line() +
  xlab('lb')
```

**Here is the outcome for BIC**

[image: My result for BIC]

Please what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: not really looking into it, but it's perfectly normal that BIC and RMSE disagree, BIC is different from RMSE alone, as it adds a penalty for model complexity

Comment: What and what do you think go along with `RMSE` in this case?